# install4j giving "install4j: compilation failed. Reason: Password might be wrong. (Windows)"

Tags: maven, install4j

We are using install4j 7.0.12 with JDK 1.8  and when building in linux giving below error (--win-keystore-password' password is wrong ) , whereas password of the keystore is correct . and we are passing the password from pom.xml only . same build is ruuning fine in local (windows ) .
Please advise

15:12:58 The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
15:12:58 not part of the command.
15:12:59 [INFO] install4j version 7.0.12 (build 7368), built on 2019-06-25
15:12:59 [INFO] Using Java 1.8.0_181 from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-7.b13.el7.x86_64/jre
15:12:59 [INFO] Registered to
15:12:59 [INFO]  15:12:59 [INFO] Loading config file /home/jdk_install/compl/target/installer/my-setup.install4j
15:13:01 [INFO] install4j: compilation failed. Reason: Password might be wrong. (Windows)

Please advise

one update , just found that this failing  at this plugin
install4j-maven-plugin:1.1.1:compile (compile-installers)

Comment: This is related to password for the code signing certificate. It could also be that the certificate file is incomplete and misses intermediate certificates. You should try with the latest version of install4j which may give you a better error message.

Comment: Quoting may be your problem. Look into this : _ The ' characters around the executable and arguments are 15:12:58 not part of the command._

Comment: Thanks @IngoKegel , we are using install4j 7.0.12 which is working fine jdk 12 but  with jdk 17 only its giving issue that is only in linux environment whereas in windows its working fine.

Comment: install4j 7 will not run with JDK 17

Comment: thanks @IngoKegel ,if  i upgrade to latest install4j , it has support with JDK17 ?

Comment: Yes, install4j 10 is bundled with Java 17